# Regex to extract column definitions from a SQL Query

Tags: c#, regex

Consider the following queries:

```
select
    foo,
    bar,
    yourmom
from
    theTable

select top 10 *
from
    theTable

select distinct foo, bar + 1, yourmom from theTable
```

I want a regex query that would extract:

```
foo,
bar,
yourmom

*

foo, bar + 1, yourmom
```

respectively.

I tried `^\sselect\s(distinct\s)?(top\s\d*)?(?'columns'.*\s)from[\s.]*$`, which I thought would work, but doesn't.  I've been playing with it for a while now and I still cannot get it to work in all three test cases.  Can someone help me with their regex-fu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: First you need to make .-match every character including newline. In java you can set the DOTALL flag, but in C# I believe you should use the `RegexOptions.SingleLine` option.

Then this expression should work:

```
^\s*select\s+(?:distinct\s+)?(?:top\s+\d*\s+)?(?'columns'.*?)from.*$
```

Comment: This does not match on the test cases.

Comment: Ok. I fixed it and updated the answer. And I verified it this time!

Answer (score 1):

I think that it would actually be easier to write a "proper" parser for SQL queries (check [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/): it's awesome and comes with a SQL example) than using regular expressions.

Comment: "Easier" is a relative term.  The column list is fairly regular; I need nothing else, certainly not a whole new library to learn.

Comment: I think that Irony is easy to learn, and it will provide a flexibility that regular expressions will not give you in this case. Then, of course, it's your choice...

Comment: When I have the time to examine Irony, I will, but for now the easiest answer was provided by barsju.